# Specific Modular Arithmetic Question with Exponentiation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Are there any theorems that can be used to reduce $1213^{797} \pmod {2591}$ without using a computer?

Comment: See this as an example of the many times this has been asked http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373144/large-modular-exponent-arithmetic?rq=1. Regards

Comment: You can do this with a regular old 8-digit pocket calculator using [the good ol' square-and-multiply algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Reduce all the intermediate results mod $2591$ to prevent overflows. If $2591$ were not a prime, you could also use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.