# Calculating $1819^{13} \pmod{2537}$ using Fermat's little theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Can anyone make me understand how to calculate $1819^{13} \pmod{2537}$ using Fermat's little theorem? Here $p=2537$ and $p-1=2537-1=2536$.

I am unable to understand how to express $1819^{13}$ in terms of $1819^{2536}$.

Comment: $2537=43\cdot59$ is not prime.

Comment: So we use Euler's theorem.

Comment: Actually the problem asked by me is a part of a numerical problem based on RSA algorithm in Cryptography.There you have two prime numbers say a=43 and b=59 which you have to multiply and get a number n that is equal to 2537.The next part is what I have asked above where I have currently got stuck.

Comment: I doubt you get any reduction out of Little Fermat here given that $13$ is a relatively small exponent. To prevent overflows in the program you can use the ideas linked to in the comments to [another question from today](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/437939/11619). Here you CAN also use the Chinese Remainder Theorem given that you know $a$ and $b$. However, $13$ is smaller than either of those, so you want save much there either (unless $2537^2$ already overflows with your chosen integer type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check description of [RSA in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) you will find that for the modulus $n = 2537 = 43\cdot 59$ we first calculate $\phi(n) = 42\cdot 58 = 2436$. Now from the problem you have mentioned it seems that $e = 13$ is encryption key and $m = 1819$ is the message.

The modular exponentiation is simple by squaring and we can write

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}1819^{13}\pmod{2537} &= 1819^{8 + 4 + 1}\pmod{2537}\\
&= 1819^{8}\cdot 1819^{4}\cdot 1819\pmod{2537}\\
&= 1819^{2^{3}}\cdot 1819^{2^{2}}\cdot 1819\pmod{2537}\\
&= 513^{2^{2}}\cdot 513^{2}\cdot 1819\pmod{2537}\\
&= 1858^{2}\cdot 1858\cdot 1819\pmod{2537}\\
&= 1844 \cdot 1858 \cdot 1819 \pmod{2537}\\
&= 2081 \pmod{2537}\end{aligned}$

You also need to find the decryption key $d$ such that $ed = 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$. This requires you to find HCF of $e = 13$ and $\phi(n) = 2436$ which is clearly $1$, but we need to express this HCF in form $13x + 2436y = 1$ and then $x$ will be your decryption key $d$. For this we proceed as below.

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}1 &= 3 - 2\\
&= 3 - (5 - 3)\\
&= 2 \cdot 3 - 1\cdot 5\\
&= 2\cdot(13 - 2\cdot 5) - 1\cdot 5\\
&= 2\cdot 13 - 5\cdot 5\\
&= 2\cdot 13 - 5\cdot(2436 - 187 \cdot 13)\\
&= 937\cdot 13 - 5\cdot 2436\end{aligned}$

so that $d = 937$. It will take time (again by modular exponentiation) to verify that from the ciphertext $c = 2081$ we can get $m = 1819$ by calculating $c^{d}\pmod{2537} = 2081^{937}\pmod{2537}$

Comment: Thank you Mr.Paramanand for your reply.Yes,2081 is the correct answer.I understood the calculation of d beforehand,I was only having problem in understanding the calculation of the encrypted message by modular exponentiation.Can you please explain to me how have you got 513,then 1858,1844 and finally 2081?

Comment: Well C_beginner there are no secrets here and no use of Fermat's theorem or other theorem is made. Idea is simply that I first multiply 1819 with itself and then divide the result by 2537 to get remainder 513. Then multiply 513 by itself and divide by 2537 to get remainder 1858. And if we divide $1858^{2}$ by 2537 then we get remainder 1844. All this calculation I did by windows calculator (it can also be done by hand). If you are using C program then please use long int's for all the calculations.

Comment: C_beginner, you should also have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation where this method is explained in detail. Basic idea is to write the exponent in binary (i.e as sums of powers of 2). This means that you will never have to calculate any power more than 2 and finally some multiplication at the end.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh how did $1819^{2^3}$ become $513^{2^2}$?

Comment: To Erik Vesterlund: Its all modulo 2537. Since $1819^{2} = 513\pmod{2537}$ if we raise each side to power $4$ we get $1819^{8} = 513^{4}\pmod{2537}$ which is what you have asked. The idea of using powers of $2$ is that once we get one remainder it can be used for repeated squaring. Details are available in the wikipedia link in my previous comment.